# Cannot resolve 'rxjs/internal/operators' while using ngx-alerts in angular 5

Tags: angular

I have a problem like this. I am building an angular app. In there I am using the ngx-alert module. This is my module.ts file.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {ROUTING} from "./app.routing";
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FlashMessagesModule } from 'angular2-flash-messages';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AlertModule } from 'ngx-alerts';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './admin/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { AdminpannelComponent } from './admin/adminpannel/adminpannel.component';

import { AuthGuard} from './shared/auth.guard';
import {UserService} from './shared/user.service';




@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    AdminpannelComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    ROUTING,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FlashMessagesModule.forRoot(),
    AlertModule.forRoot({maxMessages: 5, timeout: 5000})
  ],
  providers: [
    UserService,
    AuthGuard
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This the component.ts file where I am using alert messages.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService} from '../../shared/user.service';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import {ReservationService} from '../../shared/reservation.service';
import { FlashMessagesService } from 'angular2-flash-messages';


import { Reservation } from '../../shared/reservation';
import {AlertService} from "ngx-alerts";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-adminpannel',
  templateUrl: './adminpannel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./adminpannel.component.css'],
  providers: [UserService,ReservationService]
})
export class AdminpannelComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private userService: UserService,private router: Router, private reservationService: ReservationService,private alertService: AlertService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if(this.userService.loggedIn()) {
      this.userService.getProfile().subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res)
      })
    }

    this.getNotConfirmedReservations();
  }

  logoutUser(){
    this.userService.logout();
    this.router.navigate(['/adminlogin']);
  }

  getNotConfirmedReservations(){
    this.reservationService.getNotConfirmedReservationList().subscribe( (res) => {
      this.reservationService.reservations = res as Reservation[];
    });
  }

  confirm(id){
    this.reservationService.confirm(id).subscribe( (res) => {
        this.getNotConfirmedReservations();
        this.alertService.success('Succesfully Confirmed');
    });
  }

  // remove(id){
  //   this.reservationService.remove(id).subscribe( (res) => {
  //     this.getNotConfirmedReservations();
  //
  //   });
  // }
}
```

This is my package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.1.0",
    "angular-flash-message": "^3.4.0",
    "angular2-flash-messages": "^2.0.5",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "ngx-alerts": "^3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

When I hit ng-serve it gives me an error saying that.

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/ngx-alerts/fesm5/ngx-alerts.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/internal/operators' in 'C:\Users\thari\Desktop\Web-Project\Tharindu\frontend\node_modules\ngx-alerts\fesm5'
 @ ./node_modules/ngx-alerts/fesm5/ngx-alerts.js 4:0-53
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts
```

I search for this on the internet but I was unable to find a suitable solution which satisfies my requirement. Can someone help me to find out a solution to this problem?.

Thank you!

Comment: If you are using angular 6, then it might be due to update in rxjs and code in ngx-alerts is not updated. Try updating ngx-alerts. If doesn't work, install rxjs-compat package. This should take care of that issue hopefully. Refer(Search for rxjs-compat): https://alligator.io/angular/angular-6/

Comment: I am using angular 5

Comment: Try using older version of rxjs like 5.*

Comment: Just a thought, if people mixed 5 and 6, maybe you should install `rxjs-compat`

Comment: I am getting the same error with angular 5.2 and RXJS 5.5.10. Did you get any resolution to this error ? please suggest.

Comment: Yet I have not got any solution. Stil I am facing to the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

With Angular 6, the suggestion by @lifetimeLearner007 worked for me:

[image]

It wasn't added by the Angular CLI, so I just ran:

> npm install ngx-alerts --save

And it sorted things out.